# Ubuntu 13.04 freezes after boot or suspend (every other time)

Tags: 13.04, freeze, suspend

I'm running 13.04 on Asus UL30A

Process: Genuine Intel® CPU U7300 @ 1.30GHz × 2 
Graphics: Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset 
OS type: 64-bit

Everything completely freezes after every other a boot or suspend. No keyboard or mouse. It happens every other time. It freezes, I reboot and it works work. Next time I will reboot, it will freeze again.

This never happened with 12.10.

Any advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you're seeing a GPU lockup.

I've experienced this on my Intel based Thinkpad X220 laptop, and there's a few bugs filed for various flavours of GPU lockup.

Such as this one:- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1029443

May also be one of these upstream bugs:- https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=53379
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=53385

Comment 4 & 5 on this bug give a suggestion which works for one user:- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1043562

"Tim: please test with sna turned on, put this in /etc/X11/xorg.conf:

```
Section "Device"
 Identifier "intel"
 driver "intel"
 Option "Accelmethod" "sna"
EndSection
```

"

Might be worth a punt?